# Any practical way to mount Amazon Cloud Drive as network volume on Mac?

Tags: filesystem, mount, python, aws

Need to mount **Amazon Cloud Drive** as a desktop network volume. I've tried [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com), but it's so slow as to be useless. It also completely freezes up Finder every few seconds.

I also saw [acd_fuse](https://github.com/handyman5/acd_fuse) but not sure how to install it ... through Python? Homebrew? Is it reliable?

Comment: The original docs of for the product can be done on the GCA. See link. https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyamazonclouddrive/ -- this may help.

Comment: Check out this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/3uj5v4/experienced_amazon_cloud_drive_users_tips_useful/) for an overview of options. I have been using ACD mainly for backups with Arq by now, but mounting with ExpanDrive Version 5.4.5 (5.4.5.0) seemed to work fine as well and quite speedy - maybe you wanna give it another try?

Comment: In that [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/3uj5v4/experienced_amazon_cloud_drive_users_tips_useful/) others have reported >50 MBytes per second when using multiple threads with acd_cli `acdcli upload -x 10 folder/`